# How to send a message after the player close the game in Facebook Instant Game

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger, instant

I am struggling to know how to send a message after the player close the game .

Hi !
I am developing a simple Messenger instant game , with a messaging bot , my instant game works properly but my bot does not send any messages , i set it to send a message after the game is closed but nothing happen .
i am struggling with this and i do not know how to solve it .
the code in this image is explaining how to send a message when the player close the game , but i wonder where to put it ( in the server part hosted in Glitch.com ) , as long as the "event" parameter does not exist in the webhook page provided by Facebook documentation , can anyone help me please ?
Thanks in advance .
this is my webhook configuration code on Glitch :
  https://glitch.com/edit/#!/heady-rabbit

[image]

Comment: _“as long as the "event" parameter does not exist in the webhook page provided by Facebook documentation”_ - what do you mean by that? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_game_plays describes the event/callback.

Comment: @04FS i just want to know where i need to put the code in the image ?

Comment: Couldn’t tell you, I am not familiar with whatever this “glitch” thing is. They should have documentation telling you what goes where, I suppose?

Comment: Yes , you're right , i have sent them a message , they need to explain more !